Traces for Kafka based application with Istio and Zipkin
Currently, I am running Istio v1.20 in Kubernetes (Azure) along with Zipkin (comes with Skywalking instance).
I have couple of services which connects to Kakfa and redis via headless service to send/receive data. I am not seeing any traces for services which connects to kafka/redis. Rest of the http/grpc services traces are showing up.
kafka-controller-0.kafka-controller-headless.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local
redis-master-0.redis-headless.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local
Does Istio support tcp connections?
I tried adding service entries for kafka while coming across this article but that did not help.
I also tried increasing the trace sampling which is set at 1% by default but did not see any difference.
I am using following istio configuration:
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: istio-shared-configmap-asm-1-20
  namespace: aks-istio-system
data:
  mesh: |-
    accessLogFile: /dev/stdout
    defaultConfig:
      holdApplicationUntilProxyStarts: true
      tracing:
        randomSamplingPercentage: 100.0
        zipkin:
          address: skywalking-oap.aks-istio-system.svc:9411
      envoyAccessLogService:
        address: skywalking-satellite.aks-istio-system.svc:11800
      envoyMetricsService:
        address: skywalking-satellite.aks-istio-system.svc:11800
      proxyStatsMatcher:
        inclusionRegexps:
           - ".*manager.lds.*"
           - ".*downstream_cx.*"
           - ".*downstream_rq.*"
           - ".*upstream_cx.*"
           - ".*outlier_detection.*"
           - ".*membership_healthy.*"
           - ".*upstream_cx_active.*"
           - ".*upstream_cx_total.*"
           - ".*upstream_rq_active.*"
           - ".*upstream_rq_total.*"
           - ".*upstream_rq_pending_active.*"
           - ".*lb_healthy_panic.*"
           - ".*upstream_cx_none_healthy.*"
    enableEnvoyAccessLogService: true
    enablePrometheusMerge: true
    enableTracing: true
    extensionProviders:
      - skywalking:
          service: skywalking-satellite.aks-istio-system.svc.cluster.local
          port: 11800
        name: skywalking
      - zipkin:
          service: skywalking-oap.aks-istio-system.svc.cluster.local
          port: 9411
        name: zipkin
    defaultProviders:
      tracing: 
      - zipkin

If any proxy are needed for services, do let me know. I am new to Istio so any suggestion would be helpful
Proxy Logs from service
[2024-05-07T18:20:44.784Z] "- - -" 0 - - - "-" 40 3294 96 - "-" "-" 
"-" "-" "10.244.0.207:9092" outbound|9092||kafka-controller- 
headless.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local 10.244.0.216:51860 
10.244.0.207:9092 10.244.0.216:51858 - -
[2024-05-07T18:20:44.883Z] "- - -" 0 - - - "-" 76 3638 96 - "-" "-" 
"-" "-" "10.244.0.207:9092" outbound|9092||kafka-controller- 
headless.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local 10.244.0.216:51876 
10.244.0.207:9092 10.244.0.216:51874 - -
[2024-05-07T18:20:44.981Z] "- - -" 0 - - - "-" 1896 452 12 - "-" "- 
" "-" "-" "10.244.0.207:9092" outbound|9092||kafka-controller- 
headless.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local 10.244.0.216:51890 
10.244.0.207:9092 10.244.0.216:51884 - -
[2024-05-07T18:20:45.086Z] "POST /alarm.AlarmInterface/AddAlarms 
HTTP/2" 200 - via_upstream - "-" 208 0 20 19 "-" "grpc- 
python/1.63.0 grpc-c/40.0.0 (linux; chttp2)" "4bdc1d50-920c-4b5a- 
bee8-51835ec259a1" "<application>. 
<namespace>.svc.cluster.local:5010" "10.244.2.42:5010" 
outbound|5010||<application>.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local 
10.244.0.216:43362 10.0.208.142:5010 10.244.0.216:58302 - default
[2024-05-07T18:20:45.183Z] "- - -" 0 - - - "-" 40 3294 14 - "-" "-" 
"-" "-" "10.244.0.207:9092" outbound|9092||kafka-controller- 
headless.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local 10.244.0.216:51908 
10.244.0.207:9092 10.244.0.216:51894 - -
[2024-05-07T18:20:45.285Z] "- - -" 0 - - - "-" 76 3638 95 - "-" "-" 
"-" "-" "10.244.0.207:9092" outbound|9092||kafka-controller- 
headless.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local 10.244.0.216:51912 
10.244.0.207:9092 10.244.0.216:51910 - -
[2024-05-07T18:20:45.382Z] "- - -" 0 - - - "-" 1900 452 11 - "-" "- 
" "-" "-" "10.244.0.207:9092" outbound|9092||kafka-controller- 
headless.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local 10.244.0.216:51916 
10.244.0.207:9092 10.244.0.216:51914 - -

Injection Output
istio-proxy aspnet-core istio-proxy console istio-proxy aspnet-core 
istio-proxy aspnet-core istio-proxy postgresql istio-proxy nginx 
istio-proxy webapp-frontend istio-proxy kafka istio-proxy keycloak 
istio-proxy aspnet-core istio-proxy redis istio-proxy aspnet-core 
istio-proxy smtp4dev istio-proxy monitor istio-proxy aspnet-core


Istio does support tracing for TCP traffic, but it's more limited compared to HTTP traffic. The tracing for TCP services in Istio might not provide detailed request-level traces as seen with HTTP services. Instead, it generally includes connection establishment and connection close events. Ensure that the Kafka and Redis pods are injected with the Istio sidecar proxies. If they are not automatically injected, you may need to manually annotate these deployments to enable sidecar injection.

If Kafka and Redis are not part of the mesh but are external services, you need to ensure you have ServiceEntry resources configured for them. Your Istio configuration seems correctly set up to send tracing data to Zipkin. However, you might want to double-check if the address configuration for Zipkin and Skywalking is correct and reachable from the sidecar proxies. Also share the logs- kubectl logs <pod-name> -n <namespace> -c istio-proxy and the sidecar injection output - kubectl get pods -n <namespace> -o jsonpath="{.items[*].spec.containers[*].name}"

Yes kakfa, redis are part of mesh and you are right, I do see connection of kafka and redis but not more than that. After coming across following article, seems like traces needs to send with headers.  Currently, services are using aiokafka library to send/receive data.

Do you know if its possible to change some configuration from Kafka side in order help with traces. Would adding envoy filters help?

Hmm.. Have you tried Envoy Filter Metrics? Create an Istio Envoy Filter to intercept and parse Kafka traffic. Something like this- filterChain:             filter:               name: "envoy.filters.network.tcp_proxy"       patch:         operation: INSERT_BEFORE         value:           name: "envoy.filters.network.kafka_broker"

I tried my luck with Kafka Envoy filters but seems like Azure has blocked updating proxy filters so no luck on that side either -https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/configuration/listeners/network_filters/kafka_broker_filter
